# Bazaarvoice API V5.3

Tags: api

is there anyone on here familiar with [Bazaarvoice and their 5.3 api](http://developer.bazaarvoice.com/)?  I am trying to figure how to get reviews for products based on the Helpfulness field.  I can't find any reference to using this field anywhere and what the parameter value it is looking for might be (true, false, yes, no, etc.).

```
http://reviews.apitestcustomer.bazaarvoice.com/bvstaging/data/reviews.json?apiversion=5.3&passkey=kuy3zj9pr3n7i0wxajrzj04xo&filter=AdditionalField_Helpfulness:eq:yes
```

I would also like to know if you can do a search with multiple search terms instead of just one.

```
http://reviews.apitestcustomer.bazaarvoice.com/bvstaging/data/reviews.json?apiversion=5.3&passkey=kuy3zj9pr3n7i0wxajrzj04xo&search=dress
```

If anyone has any experience with this or has a contact they could share, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

None of the reviews in the APITestCustomer data set have helpfulness / feedback votes associated with them, so it's hard to find out the answer to your first question.

You can verify this with

```
filter=TotalFeedbackCount:gt:0
```

and see that you get no results.  If there were feedback votes, I would expect the Helpfulness field to be floating-point number that you could sort the reviews by to find the most helpful one.

For the search text, you can OR values by just listing them with a space (URL-encoded)

```
search=really%20love
```

and require them to be in a phrase with

```
search="really%20love"
```

Many typical search operators should work if you URL encoded them properly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for anyone new finding this:

```
TotalFeedbackCount:gt:0

TotalPositiveFeedbackCount:gt:0 

TotalNegotiveFeedbackCount:gt:0
```